# Quadratic Division without factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

A similar question already exists asking how to divide two quadratic functions, but it is solved by factoring and using the greatest common denominator.

If I have $f(x)=\frac{3x^2-2x+2}{x^2+2x+2}$, What is the domain and range of this function?

What I am trying to do is find the domain of the inverse function to solve for the range, but I cannot find the inverse function. So far, I have $x=\frac{3y^2-2y+2}{y^2+2y+2}$ and I need to solve for y in terms of x. How can I do so?

Comment: Simplify by removing the denominator, separate the $y$ terms from the non-$y$ terms, and complete the square.

Comment: Why not differentiating $f(x)$?

Comment: sorry how would separating the y terms from the non-y terms work? I get xy^2 + 2xy + 2 = 3y^2 - 2y +2. What do I do from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $y$ for $f(x)$, render

$3x^2-2x+2=y(x^2+2x+2)$

Then make a quadratic equation for $x$:

$(y-3)(x^2)+(2y+2)(x)+(2y-2)=0$

The only values of $y$ that can be reached with real values of $x$ are those where the discriminant is nonnegative:

$(2y+2)^2-4(y-3)(2y-2)\ge0; -4y^2+40y-20=-4(y^2-10y+5)\ge0$

The limits of the range are then the roots of $y^2-10y+5=0$.  Since the quadratic coefficient is negative, the values of $y$ that give positive discriminant and thus real values for $x$ lie between rather than beyond these limits.